# Struts 2 - Conditionallly display elements on page based on validation errors

Tags: validation, jsp, struts2

I'm looking into the fielderror tag for struts and was wondering if it was possible to conditionally show certain elements on the page based on whether or not there are any validation errors.  I want to do something like this (which currently does not do what i want it to):

```
<s:fielderror>
    <a href="test.html">This is a test link</a>
    <s:param>field1</s:param>
    <s:param>field2</s:param>
    <s:param>field2</s:param>
</s:fielderror>
```

I would like the anchor tag to show up ONLY if one of the fields referenced by the param tags is invalid.  In other words, if something is invalid in this fielderror block, I would like to display some HTML.  The way it is coded above, the anchor tag is always displayed.

I think I can certainly do this with jQuery, but i was wondering if there was a way to do this natively in Struts that perhaps I'm overlooking.  I've tried looking at things like the label and title attribute, but nothing seems to be working.

thanks in advance!

~j

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing out-of-the-box, at least not like the way you want it.

Personally, I find your construct quite counter-intuitive: it doesn't execute/render like it reads.

A few options: do it "manually", create a tag to do it, or do it outside of the view. All rely on using `ValidationAware.getFieldErrors()` to grab the map and do some minimal logic.

The manual approach would use `<s:if>` to check for the presence of `fieldErrors['fieldName']` for each field. Wrapped up in a simplistic JSP-based custom tag would produce something like:

```
<if:fieldErrors for='field1, field2, field3'>
    <a ...>
</if:fieldErrors>
```

IMO doing most of the work in Java is cleaner, and easier to test. This could mean doing all the work in the action (or utility) and exposing only a single flag to the view, or using a thin JSP-based tag to call the utility. Either way, it's easier to test outside of a container, and removes inappropriate view logic.

Comment: +1 Server side logic handling is more appropriate than polluting the view.

Comment: I apologize, I don't fully understand what you're proposing.   I don't really have any knowledge of how to use custom tags, unfortunately and I'm not sure how to use the getFieldErrors() method.  You mentioned to use `<s:if>` but then your example uses `<if:fieldErrors>`.  Can you elaborate a little bit on how that works?  Or is there possibly some documentation somehwere i can look at to better understand this?

Comment: @jacosta The s:if tag is for checking the field error map manually. See the API docs for how to use a method. The if:fieldErrors is a hypothetical custom tag that would wrap up functionality to keep a lot of logic out of the mainline JSP. Doing it all on the server side and exposing only a boolean makes most of that effort go away.

Comment: @jacosta No problem; I probably should have broken up the examples in a better way. Sorry for the confusion.